# jQuery Lightbox - Close Button Scrolls Through Images Before Closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I'm designing a website using Blogger and I just added a jQuery Lightbox plugin to my 'Edit HTML' section. It pops up fine and looks awesome but, the problem is that, when I click the 'CloseX' to close the Lightbox, it scrolls through all the images in the gallery before it actually closes. I have searched everywhere and have yet to find a fix. If someone could help me, I would greatly appreciate it.

I used this tutorial and followed it word-for-word, just for personal reference.

http://helplogger.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/add-custom-jquery-lightbox-to-blogger.html

Here's a link to my website images page, where the Lightbox is in action; along with the close bug/glitch.

http://el33tjock.blogspot.co.uk/p/images.html

Comment: if you want help you're really gonna have to post some (as little as possible to fully inform us) of your code.. we're not gonna dig through the source files of your website

Comment: but the lightbox on that tutorial page has the same error, so it's not weird that yours has it if you followed that word-for-word:) I think some element is positioned over the close button, so you're not actually clicking the close button, but instead the image's div or something, causing the lightbox to go to the next image. And at the last image, the lightbox will close automatically, even if you click the image - just as on the tutorial page.

Comment: yep, it's the next-button. Just (preferably in Chrome) right-click the close button, and choose "Inspect Element" in the popup-menu. The Developer Tool will appear, and you'll see that the next-button-area is positioned fully over the close-button (move your mouse over the selected element in the Developer Tool, to see the selection on the webpage).

Comment: see my answer below..

Answer (score 0):

That's because the next-button('s activator plate) is positioned over the close button (see image):

[image]
**full size: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOcqT.png**

---

1. Right-click the close button, and choose "Inspect Element" in the popup-menu.
2. The Developer Tool will appear, and you'll see that the next-button-area is positioned fully over the close-button.
3. Move your mouse over the selected element in the Developer Tool, to see the selection on the webpage.

---

**Just change the height of that button.**
(To be perfectly clear, not the image of the button, but the activator/pressure plate or whatever you wanna call it; the blue thing that's over the close button in the picture.)

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question. Much appreciated. I believe you have located the root of the problem. I inspected the Close Button element and played around with it for a while. I was able to rectify the problem by changing the height from 920px to 520px. However, I have absolutely no idea how to apply the change to the actual 'edit html' in Blogger. This is driving me crazy. I feel like I'm so close but so far away. If you can help further, that would be awesome. If not, thank you so much for replying anyway.

Comment: Hmm, you're gonna have to fill me in a little bit there.. I have absolutely no experience with Blogger. Does that link to your site have anything to do with Blogger, or is that a separate site?

Comment: Okay, I understand .blogspot.co.uk is from Google's Blogger. In the tutorial you linked to in your question, at *Step 3* they tell you to copy-paste CSS-code. In that code, there is this line: `#lightbox-nav-btnPrev,#lightbox-nav-btnNext{width:49%;height:100%;zoom:1;display:block;}`. If you change the height there, I would think that would fix it. If I'm missing something, please let me know, I'm not exactly sure how that Blogger stuff works..

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. I messed around with the height and, unfortunately, it did absolutely nothing. Changed zoom and display also and neither worked. This is so frustrating. My apologies. Your patience is very much appreciated.

Comment: Yeah that's pretty weird, I already noticed that in that line from the tutorial it says `height:100%;`, and on your website it's hardcoded to `height:920px;`. that height must be set somewhere else then.. only thing I can recommend is searching through all the source code you can access and search for `#lightbox-nav-btnPrev` and `#lightbox-nav-btnNext`. It's very hard for me to get a better grip on the problem because I don't have the exact source code from your situation

Comment: Thanks anyway buddy. I really appreciate the effort. :)